# How to reuse C++ classes from one project to another without copying

Tags: c++, include

I am facing the following problem:

I have a project which contains math classes (.h and .cpp files).
I want to use these classes in a different project (not int he same solution) but I can't.

In the new project I add a path to the include files of my math project. When I try to #include them it works and I can see my classes but upon trying to use them I get "Unresolved external". I haven't created a .dll or a .lib so I really don't know what's causing this.

If you have any suggestions, I`ll appreciate it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: " I haven't created a .dll or a .lib so I really don't know what's causing this." Not creating an using a library is what's causing it.

Comment: You might want to create a separate library project for the shared parts, and then use that in your other projects.

Comment: I suspect all those "unresolved externals" are in the .cpp implementation files that you never added to your new project. And you would have the *identical* problem in your original project if you simply removed the .cpp files from there. You *can* share source files across multiple projects, but doing so is a sign a dll/lib is likely on the menu, rather than replicating compiled translation units all over the place.

Comment: You get unres.externals because your project can't find implementations of the functions defined in headers. You have 3 ways to approach this: 1) make your math a static or dynamic library and link it 2) make your math library header-only (move implementations into headers) 3) add source files of math project to your new project (don't do this :) )

Comment: Thank you for the response guys! It was as Christian suggested below, I was supposing that the linker is a magical being and that it can know everything I do. 

Creating a .lib solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to #include them it works and I can see my classes but
>   upon trying to use them I get "Unresolved external". I haven't created
>   a .dll or a .lib so I really don't know what's causing this.

That you have not created a library is precisely the *reason* why you get the error. The compilation units in your new project (*"the `*.cpp` files"*) include the headers for your classes and make use of the class definitions, but the definitions of the members are missing.

For example, let's say you have a file called `"c.h"` in your old project:

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

class C
{
public:
    C();
    void f();
};

#endif
```

Some `*.cpp` file in your new project includes the header and uses the class:

```
#include "somepath/oldproject/c.h"

void someFunction()
{
    C c;
    c.f();
}
```

This compiles fine, but it will cause linker errors, because the **definitions of `C::C` and `C::f`** will be missing.

Now, the clean solution to this is certainly *not* adding `somepath/oldproject/c.cpp` from your old project to your new project, although that would fix the linker error, but to employ a library-based approach. Turn your math classes into a library project, let's call it "Math Utils", which produces a `*.lib` file (as you seem to be on Windows), for example `math-utils.lib`. Add the library's include and release path to your global include and library paths. Then add the `math-utils.lib` file to the new project's linker dependencies.

And change the code in your new project to:

```
#include <math-utils/c.h>

void someFunction()
{
    C c;
    c.f();
}
```

Do the same thing in the old project! You will end up with three different projects. Two application projects and one library project, the former two depending on the latter.

Creating your own libraries for the first time can be a bit intimidating, but the benefits are worth the trouble.

---

See also [The Linker Is not a Magical Program](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Linker_Is_not_a_Magical_Program).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Christian! I made a small test and was able to load the functions and use them with the .lib 

I thought it was going to be like including GLM where you don't need dll or static lib but it`s probably a different case there :)

Again, thank you very much!